# DeepL API Translation Error Apex Integration

Tags: salesforce, document, apex, lwc, deepl

Has anyone encountered this error with "DeepL API' when trying to upload and translate a document?:Failed to open the uploaded document?

The document id and key are retrieved but when I handle the endpoint for the status I get that it cannot be opened, does anyone know how to get the file data exactly since it isn't related to a record and I don't want to upload it to my salesforce org, just to handle the binary data directly?